# VB.NET Auto Save Text File Mulitple

Tags: vb.net, loops

So i declare save text file without using save file dialog.

```
Private Sub strt2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles strt2.Click
        Directory.CreateDirectory("Result/Combolist")
        Using sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("Result/Combolist/" & "\Email&Pass[" & time & "].txt")
            sw.WriteLine(rslt1.Text)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

So i want to make save text file that doesn't replace text file that can i save mulitple text file, i want every i click start button it create new save text file. what code can i use?

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing. You say you want to "automatically save" the text file, and then immediately after you say "every time you click a button it creates a new auto save text file?" Clicking a button is manual. Anyway, if you're trying to auto-save a file, but also click a button to save it manually, you'd want to put the save code in a Sub or Function, and then call that Sub/Function from a timer, and also the button you want to click.

Comment: i mean for the auto saving is no need to use save file dialog

Comment: Check these values: `Application.UserAppDataPath`, `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath`, `Application.CommonAppDataPath`. You have rights to write to these paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears thst you're trying to use the current time to distinguish the filenames, which is often reasonable, so perhaps something like this will work better:

```vb
Private Sub strt2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles strt2.Click
    Dim timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")
    Dim fileName = "Email&Pass[" & timeStamp & "].txt"
    Dim baseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Dim resultDir = (Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(baseDir, "Result\Combolist"))).FullName

    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(resultDir, fileName), rslt1.Text)

End Sub
```

It's best to use an absolute path when using files, as otherwise it can be confusing when it is looking somewhere else to where you think it is looking.

If you then wanted to get the file with the latest time in its filename, you could do something like:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

' other code here maybe '

Private Sub rslt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rslt.Click
    Dim baseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Dim resultDir = Path.Combine(baseDir, "Result\Combolist")

    Dim latestTimeStamp = ""
    Dim re As New Regex("^Email&Pass\[([0-9-]+)\]$")
    For Each f In Directory.EnumerateFiles(resultDir, "*.txt").Select(Function(g) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(g))
        If re.IsMatch(f) Then
            Dim m = re.Match(f)
            If m.Groups(1).Captures(0).Value > latestTimeStamp Then
                latestTimeStamp = m.Groups(1).Captures(0).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If latestTimeStamp <> String.Empty Then
        Dim latestFile = Path.Combine(resultDir, "Email&Pass[" & latestTimeStamp & "].txt")
        Process.Start(latestFile)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why i don't have the text file when i click the button

Comment: he didn't create new text file my directory is empty

Comment: @Gracia It should be in Result\Combolist in the current user's Documents folder.

Comment: how can i transfer the directory in same folder with the app that creating text file

Comment: Usually you would not be able to do that because the Program Files directories are not writable by ordinary users (it's an anti-malware thing). If you have a look at what is available in the [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) then perhaps you could find a good place for the data, maybe create a directory with your name or the program's name inside `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.

Comment: like this Directory.CreateDirectory("Result/Good") its create a folder in same path of the app

Comment: @Gracia You can do that if you want to, but it goes against Microsoft's guidelines for where to put files and it will break if the program is installed in Program Files on someone else's computer. It would be `Dim baseDir = Application.StartupPath()`.

Comment: how about getting result every it create new save text file then every i click result button it will open the latest create new save text file, like this

Private Sub rslt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rslt.Click
        Process.Start("Result/Combolist" & "\Email&Pass[" & timeStamp & "].txt")
    End Sub

Comment: @Gracia If you ask a new question for that, but give a link to this question, then I or someone else will be able to help with it. I *think* your new question is "How to open the file with the latest name in a directory, but not necessarily the one with the latest file write time?" But perhaps you would like to give a go first. What you need to do is extract the datetime part from the filename and get the largest one, which can be done without parsing it into a datetime because of the format used.

Comment: i mean this with the latest file write time

Comment: @Gracia I added something you might be able to use. If it doesn't work, then please create a new question for this new issue.